Test multiple functions raise the same error with pytest
Is there a way to put multiple tests under one pytest.raises block?  I'd like something similar to the below, but I would want to test that both functions raise the error (whereas I believe only one ValueError would need to be raised for pytest to be satisfied here).
with pytest.raises(ValueError):
    #I want to confirm both of these raise ValueError
    do_first_thing()
    do_second_thing()


parametrize the test?

This should be two entirely separate tests, not just two separate with blocks. Parameterization reduces the boilerplate of setting up the two tests.

Hello, parametrisation worked well (I wasn't familiar with it initially).  If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it @jonrsharpe
